# How to disable sidenav overlay in Materializecss?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have the following code:

```
    <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
        <li><a class="subheader">Scalls Seleccionados</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn waves-effect waves-light cyan"><i class="material-icons">inbox</i>Scall 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn waves-effect waves-light cyan"><i class="material-icons">inbox</i>Scall 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn waves-effect waves-light cyan"><i class="material-icons">inbox</i>Scall 3</a></li>
        <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
    </ul>
    <a data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse btn-floating btn-large cyan" style="top: 10px; left: 10px;">
        <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
    </a>
```

Do you have any idea how to disable/remove the overlay when I display the sidenav in Materializecss?

I've spend a lot of time trying to remove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IF the issue is because the overlay is overlapping the nav menu, use this CSS fix;

```
.navbar-fixed {
   z-index: 999; 
}
// the default value is 997 in materialize.min.css, which places the nav behind the overlay... :(
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it is an old question but for anyone wanting to remove the overlay the following works:-

```
.sidenav-overlay {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
}
```

or with Svelte:-

```
:global(.sidenav-overlay) {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to your css file :

```
#sidenav-overlay {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add `.sidenav-overlay{opacity: 0;}` to your css.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have also not found any specific function call to do so.
This is how disabling the sidenav without removing it from DOM.

```
var sideNavElem = $('a[data-activates="slide-out"]');

$(sideNavElem).off('click');
$(sideNavElem).click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

is it similar to what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't understand your example. But I don't want to disable the sidenav. The only thing I want to do is remove the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove it from DOM using onOpenStart event

```
$('.side-nav').sidenav({
    ..., //your sidenav options here
    onOpenStart: function(sidenav) {
        sidenav.M_Sidenav._overlay.remove();
    }
});
```